# How to migrate SitePages from 2019 to Online (classic experience)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, 2019, sitepages, online

Is it possible to migrate/copy subsites from one page (SP 2019) to another site in online? ( Classic Experience)

I was trying by SharePoint Migration tool but option "This site and all subsites" is disable. I have full permission to this site.

On other pages, this option is available.

---

I also tried this way - I copied the site page file (.aspx) using the file explorer and I tried to upload it  to the target site, but I get message " Sorry, you don't have access. "

Comment: Try using Site collection administrator account or SharePoint tenant administrator account. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately without success.